# Text cut off at bottom of page

Tags: php, html, css

The text at the bottom of certain pages on my website gets cut off. I've noticed this problem in Chrome, Firefox, and on mobile with Safari, so I'm pretty sure the problem is my code.

Screenshots:
[image: example 1]
[image: example 2]

Here is a minimal working example:

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 background: transparent;
    }

body {
 height: 100%;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

blockquote {
 font-size: 12px;
 padding: 20px;
 font-family: "Courier", serif, monospace;
 width: 50%;
}

.main h1 {
 color: #555;
 font-size: 30px;
 margin: 15px 0px;
 text-align: left;
}

.main h2 {
 color: dodgerblue;
 font-size: 24px;
 text-align: left;
}
.main h3 {
 color: black;
 font-style: italic;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: left;
}

.menu {
 padding-top: 15px;
 border-right: 3px solid #555;
 height: 100%;
 width: 263px;
 float:left;
 background-color: #555;
}

.main {
 padding-right: 100px;
 padding-left: 100px;
 padding-top: 50px; 
 padding-bottom: 100px;
 margin-left: 263px;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 text-align: justify;
}

.main a {
 color: dodgerblue;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.main a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}

.item {
 background-color: white;
 border: 2px solid #555;
 padding: 15px;
 width: auto;
 margin-bottom: 35px;
 line-height: 1.6;
}

.description {
 border-left: 4px solid dodgerblue;
 text-align: justify;
 font-size: 16px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 width: 75%;
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: #CAE6EF;
 color: black;
}

hr {
 border: 1px dashed black;
 margin: 10px 0;
}

.row:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 clear: both;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 8px;
 width: 200px;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 border: 2px dotted #f1f1f1;
 border-width: thick;
}

li a {
 display: block;
 color: #000;
 padding: 8px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

li {
 text-align: center;
 border-bottom: 0px solid #555;
}

li:last-child {
 border-bottom: none;
}

li a.active {
 background-color: #555;
 color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
 background-color: dodgerblue;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
  <html>

  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>

<div class="menu">
<center>
<BR><BR>
<?php $x=$_GET['x'];if (empty($x)) { $x="about"; } ?>
 <ul>
 <li><a class="<?php echo ($x == 'about')?'active':'';?>" href="?x=about">ABOUT</a></li>
 <li><a class="<?php echo ($x == 'news')?'active':'';?>" href="?x=news">NEWS</a></li>
 <li><a class="<?php echo ($x == 'books')?'active':'';?>" href="?x=books">BOOKS</a></li>
 <li><a class="<?php echo ($x == 'projects')?'active':'';?>" href="?x=projects">PROJECTS</a></li>
 <li><a class="<?php echo ($x == 'articles')?'active':'';?>" href="?x=articles">ARTICLES</a></li>
 <li><a class="<?php echo ($x == 'pres')?'active':'';?>" href="?x=pres">PRESENTATIONS</a></li>
 <li><a class="<?php echo ($x == 'trans')?'active':'';?>" href="?x=trans">TRANSLATIONS</a></li>
 </ul>
<BR><BR><BR>
</center>
</div>

    <div class="main">
 <?php $content=file_get_contents($x . ".html");echo $content; ?>
    </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Code from one of the pages that gets cut off:

```html
<h1>Translations</h1>
Translations without full citations are unpublished.
<BR>
<BR>
<h2 style="color:sandybrown">French</h2>
<BR>
<a href="http://barricadejournal.org/vol2issue1/only-one-solution/" target="_blank">"Only One Solution: To Remain Together!"</a>, <i>Barricade: A Journal of Antifascism & Translation</i>, Vol. 1, No. 2, 2019<BR>
<BR>
<a href="http://jffp.pitt.edu/ojs/index.php/jffp/article/view/835" target="_blank">"Logic of the Egotistical Sentence: A Reading of Descartes"</a>, <i>Journal of French and Francophone Philosophy</i>, Vol. 26, No. 1, 2018<BR>
<BR>
<a href="translations/Rachilde_The-Tooth.pdf" target="_blank">"The Tooth"</a> by Rachilde<BR>
<BR>
<a href="translations/Georges-Canguilhem_Descartes-and-Technique.pdf" target="_blank">"Descartes and Technique"</a> by Georges Canguilhem<BR>
<BR>
<a href="translations/Jacques-Derrida-on-Rimbaud.pdf" target="_blank">Derrida on Rimbaud</a><BR>
<BR>

<h2 style="color:sandybrown">Spanish</h2>  
<BR>
<a href="translations/Heriberto-Yepez_The-Postborderzone.pdf" target="_blank">"The Post-Borderzone"</a> by Heriberto Yépez<BR>
<BR>
<a href="https://muse.jhu.edu/article/603053" target="_blank">"‘Against Telephysics’ from Contra la television"</a>, <i>Postmodern Culture</i>, Vol. 25, No. 1, 2014<BR>
<BR>
"A Virtual Post-Anarchist Roundtable: An Interview with Jürgin Mümken, Anton Fernendaz de Rota, and Süreyyya Evren [Part 2]", <i>Anarchist Developments in Cultural Studies</i>, 2011<BR> 
<BR>
<a href="https://www.nodo50.org/ellibertario/english/Anarchist%20School-JML-2009.txt" target="_blank">"The Anarchist School: Education for Equality - J. Martín Luengo"</a>, <i>El Libertario</i>, 2009
<BR><BR><BR>
```

I've tried adding more `<br>` tags at the end of the content as well as adding `padding-bottom` and `margin-bottom`, but none of these attempts have made a change at all. I've noticed that the bottom arrow of the scroll bar is missing (see images) too. This seems to have something to do with the problem, but I can't figure out why it is like that.

Comment: this is the right <br /> not just <BR>. Also I am unable to view the picture, would you mind posting the image directly? or if you can use fiddle.

Comment: Is there any height provided on the parent element?

Comment: Please post your exact code since your 'working' example doesn't actually show the issue

Comment: Updated! I believe the parent element of the div height is the body (which is set to 100%)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `overflow: hidden;` in the rule for `body`, which clearly cuts off the overflow. Change that to `auto` - this should basically solve the cutting-off problem.

Comment: That does help the text become completely visible, but it creates extra white space underneath the other elements and sometimes adds two scroll bar ([example](https://jake.nabasny.com/test/?x=pres)). What I want is to have a div box that is as big as the browser window and scrolls when the content overflows (but not further down the page). Since the scrollbar that appears when there is overflow is cut off, can the problem be my height values?

Comment: Okay, it was the height values. I took them out and fixed `.menu` with the code [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_sidebar.asp). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a little padding to the bottom of the element vs using line breaks?

Hard to judge with the code pieces you posted but a blind swing